# Sending a JSONObject with retrofit using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm having trouble finding how to do a Retrofit @POST with a JSONObject.

```
interface AuthApi {
    @Multipart
    @POST("auth/login")
    suspend fun userLogin(
        @Body authResponse: JSONObject?
    ): Response<AuthResponse>
}
```

When sending I am getting an error:

> E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Body
>   parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding.

I'm pretty sure I am not sending the JSONObject the right way, but I can't find a good guide to help me with this implementation in Kotlin.

I have tried to add the:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json; charset=urf-8")
```

Directly after the `@Multipart`, to no avail. I would like to know how to correctly send my JSONObject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User `@Part` instead of `@Body`

Since your using the Multi Part encoding, it doesn't take in just one Body object. It takes in multiple `Part` parameters

Comment: I switched the @Body line to @Part("authResponse") authResponse: JSONObject?, but now I am getting an error 405.

Comment: a 405 means you hit the server and it's confirmed to be there, but you've used an unacceptable HTTP method for the request. Double check to make sure you're sending up the correct data. You might not even need for it to be a multi part request.